# Creating a formula based on TODAY's day

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-dates

I have column A (list of stock prices at close of day)

- A1=`4/1/2019` | stock price
- A2=`4/2/2019` | stock price
- A3=`4/3/2019` | stock price

each day will be added to the sheet automatically

I want to take the current days cell (a1=todays price, a2=future date price)and have it change based on the date.

how would I have that price change automatically based on the day?

**formula >> (current date price*2)*41%**

where "current date price" changes automatically based on the new data in "column a" that is received.

so when I open sheets today it would show the answer that includes A1. when I open it tomorrow that answer should change based on info now in A2.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(TODAY()), A1:B, 2, 0)*2)*41%)
```

[image: 0]